# Mountain top drainage issue

Tags: water, drainage, sump-pump, french-drain, gravel

We live atop a large hill and due to how the driveway is I constantly have water and mud on top of a small area of my driveway. This area is supposed to be a low area to care water down the driveway but the concrete falls back toward the hilltop so the water just pools. The ground is made up of mostly clay which allows the water to sit for days if not weeks before drying out. I created a french drain prior to my shop being built but it seems I don't have the needed fall for it to drain effectively and quickly. Additionally, because the dirt needs to be so low as not to run across the driveway it seems my french drain inlet is just a touch too high to capture the water and get it moved. Because the drain wrap around my building I can no longer easily access the area to dig it back up increase the fall to allow for better drainage. So I am looking for solutions that I might try to fix the pooling water and mud atop the driveway. I have been digging the dirt wall back to allow more for it to pool and hopefully absorbed into the ground better but that doesn't seem to be working. Any help is appreciated.

Would some sort of sump pump work for this area year-round? Other ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: measure and get the french drain sloping correctly. water will always flow downhill due to gravity - no pump needed.

Comment: similar:  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16973/how-can-i-prevent-water-from-pooling-in-the-street-in-front-of-my-house

Comment: Can you extend the French drain down the hill?